# MOZ_PLUGIN_VALUE Windows Environment Variable defualt value?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I was trying to install Pygame (unrelated) and accidentally changed MOZ_PLUGIN_PATH. What is the default value?

[I cropped the rest of the picture to make it clearer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g2Aj.png)
[image: my current system variables]

Answer (score 0):

I try to change value by Edit then use your old user including to set up start up missing program on new windows example : D:\user\plugins\